# declaring and passing List in playframework scala templates

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a header.scala.html file that expects a string and a list parameter

ie  `@(title: String)(scripts: List[String])`

The other scala files will reference the header and will pass specific lists eg

```
@import scala._
@{val jsList = List("a", "b")}
@views.html.header("title"){jsList}
```

However I get Compliation error - type mismatch; found : play.api.templates.Html required: java.util.List[String]

There must be some syntax issue that I'm not seeing... Anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot declare variables (like that) in Play templates. ([here's a google groups discussion about it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/hEQ33y6_kSI/CEUr5dLXGUgJ))

The first thing you can do is, if you only need the value once in your template:

```
@views.html.header("title")(List("a","b"))
```

Note that you should use `(` and `)`, I believe that everything between `{}` is interpreted as HTML code (hence your type mismatch error).

However, this isn't a suitable approach if you need it multiple times in your templates. You can then use `defining` block:

```
@defining(List("a","b")) { jsList =>

  @* using it once *@
  @views.html.header("title")(jsList)

  @* using it twice *@
  <p>My list contains @jsList.size elements.</p>

  @* ... *@
}
```