# How to create a constant using play framework 2.0 views

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

Hi I'm using the play framework in Java

I need to create a constant in a view and use it in a loop.

To illustrate this will be the code in a view

```
@for(i <- 1 to 7){
@if(i>=wd) {   //The constant wd is defined outside but in  
    <td>@cur++</td>
}else {
    <td></td>
    }
}
```

(I have to use wd many times and I think its a little ugly to pass it from the controller).
Is there no way to just create a constant?

I looked at

```
@defining(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName()) { fullName =>
  <div>Hello @fullName</div>
}
```

but this doesn't seem to help 
Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on how `@defining` "doesn't seem to help"? It should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `defining` block should be exactly what you need for this:

If your constant is limited to the template you simply wrap your whole template in the defining block:

```
@defining( 1 ){ wd =>

    @for(i <- 1 to 7){
        @if(i>=wd) {  
            <td>@cur++</td>
        } else {
            <td></td>
        }
    } 
}
```

You're also not limited to `Integer`s in there, you can define Strings, Lists, ... in there aswell.

If you want to use that constant in multiple templates, consider putting it in an `Enum` and get the value from the enum in the defining block.

Comment: Also take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974402/declaring-and-passing-list-in-playframework-scala-templates/16985503#16985503 It tells you that you cannot declare variables etc. in Play templates and how you can solve it (with a `defining` block)